# Why is the table view different size from iPhone X~iPhone XS Max?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

In storyboard, I fill table view full size.
[image]
And I set my placeholder view height set like this.

```
self.placeholderView.frame.size.height = self.mainTableView.frame.height
```

If I launch iPhone se ~ iPhone 8 Plus, good result.
[image]

But if I launch iPhone x ~ iPhone Xs Max, small size.
[image]

Even in the case of iPhone X, the table view itself is full size.
But why do I get a different size when I get a table view?
How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using a launch storyboard or launch images?  If you are using launch images, make sure you have included the correct size for iPhone X and later (or better yet, switch to using a launch storyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this instead,

```
self.table.backgroundView = yourView()
```

and if you want to set data back to the table just set

```
if table.backgroundView != nil{
   table.backgroundView = nil
}
```

I don't know if you like this idea or not but I used it every time when I change my background table view to the user that shows like no data or no internet connection.

Comment: are you sure that your tableview bottom layout constraint is equal to bottom superview? because as I seen in the picture, the placeholder view is filled up with the tableview size and also the size having that space to the bottom view is also because of safe area layout for iPhone x or upper version

Comment: or screenshot your constraints would be easy to help you :)

Comment: I'm sure that. And I check to debug view hierachy. Table view itself is full size of super view. but when I get height from code, it's defferrent size.

Comment: I have another method on how to achieve that, but do you want to do my way? because I'm not using frame

Comment: I don't care using frame or constraint